# Saxonia s9api integrated Extension functions Provide node

Tags: saxon, s9api

we are trying to submit a node using the integrated extension function. The node looks correct as far as it goes, but we can't access the individual elements, because there is always an outOfBound exception appearance.

How can we access the individual elements below the root element?

```
public ExtensionFunction updateTempNode = new ExtensionFunction() {
        public QName getName() {
            return new QName("de.dkl.dymoServer.util.ExternalFunctions", "updateTempNode");
        }

        public SequenceType getResultType() {
            return SequenceType.makeSequenceType(
                    ItemType.BOOLEAN, OccurrenceIndicator.ONE
            );
        }

        public net.sf.saxon.s9api.SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
            return new SequenceType[]{
                    SequenceType.makeSequenceType(
                            ItemType.STRING, OccurrenceIndicator.ONE),
                    SequenceType.makeSequenceType(
                            ItemType.DOCUMENT_NODE, OccurrenceIndicator.ONE)};
        }

        public XdmValue call(XdmValue[] arguments) {
            String sessionId = arguments[0].itemAt(0).getStringValue();
            SaplingElement tempNode = TransformationService.tempNodes.get(sessionId);
            ItemTypeFactory itemTypeFactory = new ItemTypeFactory(((XdmNode) arguments[1]).getProcessor());
            tempNode.withChild(
                    arguments[1].stream().map(xdmValue -> Saplings.elem(xdmValue.getStringValue()).withText(xdmValue.itemAt(0).getStringValue())).toList()
                            .toArray(SaplingElement[]::new)
            );
            System.out.println(tempNode);

            return new XdmAtomicValue(true);
        }
    };
```

[AOOB as I try to iterate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkVKd.jpg)

[Data expected as document_node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmjqr.jpg)

Comment: Please supply enough information to reproduce the problem; and please supply code as editable code, not as an image. The code in your image returns a boolean rather than a node, but the most obvious error is that SaplingElement.withChild returns a new SaplingElement object, so it's pointless to call it and ignore the result of the call.

Comment: I edited my question with the code. Thanks for the quick reply on a Sunday

Comment: So (a) what does `TransformationService.tempNodes.get(sessionId)` do, and (b) how does it fail? And (c) what's the big picture, what is this code trying to achieve?

Comment: And (d) what's the stack trace of the AOOB exception?

Comment: a. Sessionid is argument[0], just a string and works fine as expected. B. The Part failing, is regarding to argument[1], because the node transfered has to be a document_node instead seems to be a string as well C. The incoming date (expect node) has to be merged in to another node. D. Stack trace is for now only as an image available. See attachment.

Comment: If `arguments[1]` is an `XdmNode`, a document node as you say, what kind of object do you expect to find with `itemAt(1)`? A single node is a single node. It is not clear what you want to access there, I wonder whether you want to select children or grandchildren.

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to provide much clearer detail of what you are trying to accomplish. We can't work out your requirements by reverse engineering code that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry bout that. My software engineer will take over and provide everything needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess is that you want something like

```
tempNode = tempNode.withChild(
                arguments[1]
                
 .select(Steps.child().then(Steps.child()))
                            .map(childNode -> Saplings.elem(childNode.getNodeName()).withText(childNode.itemAt(0).getStringValue()))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
                            .toArray(new SaplingElement[]{})
            );
```

which would populate `tempNode` with copies of the child nodes of the root element of the document node that is arguments[1]. There might be better ways to do that.
.

Comment: Thanks, worked fine so far. Unfortunately I have to open another question were the node is merged in to another node. In this process, NPE appears.